# Can I send a google calendar invite using a custom email I created?

Tags: email, calendar, gmail, google-calendar-api

I have a default email of `foo@gmail.com` and have an alternate email that I send and receive emails from which is `hello@foo.com`(this is also from google)/

Is there a way I can send calendar invites from `hello@foo.com`? Everytime i schedule a calendar invite from google calendar, it shows up as `foo@gmail.com`.

I am not using gsuite

Comment: Can we see the code you are using now for the Google Calendar api?  You should just need to add an additional person to the event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to [upgrade from free edition to G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60217).

As it was mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?hl=en) "Other ways to get free email":

> You can use Gmail for free with a personal [Google
>   Account](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount).
>   However, you won't get a custom email address such as
>   name@company.com. Instead, your address will end in @gmail.com. You
>   also won't have any administrative control over your organization's
>   email use.